# Como saber se a data é o ultimo dia do mês?

Tags: php, data

Tenho uma data salva no banco de dados e, antes de apresentar no grid, preciso saber se ela é o último dia do mês.

Preciso desta informação para apresentá-la em uma cor diferente.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Pode fazer usando a classe [DateTime do PHP](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php).

Função de exemplo:

```
function ultimoDia($data){
    $formato = 'd/m/Y'; // define o formato de entrada para dd/mm/yyyy
    $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat($formato, $data); // define data desejada
    if($dt->format('t') === $dt->format('d')){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Uso:

```
var_dump(ultimoDia('17/08/2016')); // retorna bool(false)
var_dump(ultimoDia('30/08/2016')); // retorna bool(false)
var_dump(ultimoDia('31/08/2016')); // retorna bool(true)
```

Explicação:

`$dt->format('t')` retorna o número de dias do mês da data referenciada no objeto

`$dt->format('d')` retorna o dia da data referenciada no objeto

Comment: Muito bom, boa a ideia.

Comment: Perfeito. Muito obrigado

Comment: Porque teria a condição de ===, com 3?

Comment: Boa solução, simples e prática. Não bastaria == ?

Comment: @AndréBaill três sinais de iguais faz a comparação de igualdade valor e tipo, ou seja, exatamente iguais (mesmo valor e mesmo tipo).

Answer (score 12):

Para obter o último dia do mês basta isso:

```
date("t", $data) == date("d", $data )
```

Pode usar `gmdate` se preferir. Usualmente, para se usar em *loops*, usar números, como obtido por `time()` é muito mais eficaz do que instanciar um objeto para isso.

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/aOcEwH)**.

Usando MySQL, por exemplo, basta isto para obter a data já num formato certo para se trabalhar, sem fazer inúmeras conversões:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP( data_evento );
```

O valor retornado já vem pronto para usar em `date( ..., $data )`.

Comment: Muito boa solução com `date()`, rápido e simples

Comment: @Miguel Quase sempre date() puro é melhor e mais simples que DateTime em PHP. Depois vou melhorar a resposta e mostrar como converter `d/m/Y` em unix_timestamp, que é o mesmo formato do date()

Answer (score 8):

Mais uma outra opção seria utilizar a função [`cal_days_in_month`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.cal-days-in-month.php) que retorna o número de dias do mês e ano informados:

```
$days = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 8, 2016); // Retorna 31
echo (date('d') == $days)? 'Último dia':'';
```

A comparação é um simples [Operador Ternário](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary), que "printa" na tela caso o dia atual seja o último dia do mês, retornado pela função `cal_days_in_month`

Answer (score 7):

Uma forma mais engraçada de fazer com o [formato relativo](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) `'last day of'` ;)

```
<?php
function isLastDay($day)
{
    return date( 'd', strtotime( $day ) ) == date( 'd', strtotime( 'last day of ' . date( 'M Y' , strtotime( $day ) ) ) );
}

isLastDay("30-06-1984"); //retorna true
```

[Veja a funcionar](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3b446b26a52b9de98f38651c2bc129693c8d1beb)

Comment: É engraçado mesmo. Eu e o GuilhermeNascimento chamamos isso de "php falante"